# Where does argc come from?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, process

A new process is created by fork/exec. Exec sets up the command line arguments but I don't see that it sets up the number of those arguments to put in `argc`.

`main()` is supposed to be the first function to run in the new process but `argc` is already set by then.

Where is it set? It has to be some kind of setup code that counts parameters before `main` is called but nothing I have read explains what kinds of things this setup code does or where it resides.

Is this in `libc`?  Is this the same on every OS and covered by some specification? Where would I find what goes on in the setup code besides this? Is it called before instantiating globals?

Comment: Which language are you interested in?

Comment: The language specs detail what is in place by the time main executes. Read them to find out. Exactly what is done by OS and what is done by language runtime varies between implementations. Hard to say more because your question is a little vague. It's quite a large topic and very implementation specific.

Comment: This is very system dependent. e.g. Linux counts the items in argv in the execve syscall in the kernel (the do_execve() function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's plenty of stuff that happens in most implementations before `main` is called (usually environment set up by something similar to `crt0`, the C runtime startup).

There's also plenty of stuff that may happen *after* `main` exits, such as resource closure, `atexit` exit handlers and so forth.

The C standards only really cover the stuff that happens in terms of the language, not how implementations do their work under the covers (which is basically what you're asking). Each implementation may do things in different ways but many UNIX types will have something like the afore-mentiond `crt0` which does the setup.

Comment: Thus the crt0 link errors when you try to compile an executable without a main().  Funny that this seems to be in a no mans land between the OS specs and the language specs.  Excellent!  Thanks.

Comment: @sean Not funny at all. All systems handle processes differently. The standards provide a common interface. Naturally each implementation of the language has to provide an implementation specific bridge between the OS process start and the commencement of `main()`. In fact this is precisely what the specs are all about. Take a look at the main function for a Windows program with its 4 parameters. That style came into being before there was a C standard and is why it's not a standards compliant main function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not sure about C, but in C++ that `main` is standard compliant. The standard requires that implementations offer *at least* the no argument and the two argument versions, but explicitly allows other flavours, for which it *suggests* that extra arguments should come after argc/argv, but does not even require that. It does require that the return type is `int`, though in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The OS takes care of it. After all, it is the OS which handles threads and processes.

Comment: No, it's the job of the language runtime.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: well, I'd say that it's platform dependent.

Comment: @MatteoItalia "Where would I find what goes on in the setup code besides this? Is it called before instantiating globals?" That has to be down to the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Using fork causes to continue at the next line of code. Exec function family creates a new execution, depending in which you are using the second parameter of the function might be the array of parameters.

```
#include <unistd.h>


int ret;
char *cmd[] = { "ls", "-l", (char *)0 };
char *env[] = { "HOME=/usr/home", "LOGNAME=home", (char *)0 };
...
ret = execve ("/bin/ls", cmd, env);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, `main()` is called from `mainCRTStartup()` or a similar function dependent on your build tools. If you break in the debugger and examine the callstack you should be able to find the source.